# convert datetime is not running to view,

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, view

i tried to this query. but its not running. how can i do?

```
SELECT dbo.isemri_data.sipnum, 
       dbo.kayitlar.id, 
       dbo.kayitlar.makina_id, 
       dbo.kayitlar.personel, 
       dbo.kayitlar.isemrino, 
       dbo.kayitlar.tarih, 
       dbo.kayitlar.gercek_hiz, 
       dbo.kayitlar.durus_kod, 
       dbo.kayitlar.miktar, 
       dbo.kayitlar.fire 
FROM   dbo.isemri_data 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.kayitlar 
                    ON dbo.isemri_data.isemrino = dbo.kayitlar.isemrino 
WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dbo.kayitlar.tarih, 104) BETWEEN 
              CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '12.08.2015', 104) AND 
              CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '19.08.2015', 104) 
       AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), dbo.kayitlar.makina_id) = 'M1' 
       AND dbo.kayitlar.isemrino LIKE '%'
```

if delete

```
CONVERT(varchar(10),dbo.KAYITLAR.TARIH,104) BETWEEN convert(varchar(10),'12.08.2015',104) and convert(varchar(10),'19.08.2015',104)
```

query is running.

or if run to only main table allready running my query.

i cant find what is the problem.

Comment: What is the data type of column `dbo.kayitlar.tarih` ?

Comment: What does "it is not running" mean? Do you get an error message? Are the results not what you expect?

Comment: Post an error message

Comment: ohh sorry. query is running but not result. any error msg.

Comment: What is the data type of `dbo.kayitlar.tarih` ?

Comment: data type is datetime, but i convert as CONVERT(varchar(10),dbo.KAYITLAR.TARIH,104) for calendar sort to aspx

Comment: maybe this songs silly, but, did you check that your data accomplish your where criteria?. Can you put at least one row example data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found answer. if i use

dbo.kayitlar.tarih BETWEEN 
              CONVERT(DATETIME, '12.08.2015', 104) AND 
              CONVERT(DATETIME, '19.08.2015', 104)

running query.

thanx for your help

Answer (score 1):

Since you have mentioned the data type is Datetime , DO NOT convert it to anything else in there where clause, do it in select if you want to.

```
SELECT dbo.isemri_data.sipnum, 
       dbo.kayitlar.id, 
       dbo.kayitlar.makina_id, 
       dbo.kayitlar.personel, 
       dbo.kayitlar.isemrino, 
       dbo.kayitlar.tarih, 
       dbo.kayitlar.gercek_hiz, 
       dbo.kayitlar.durus_kod, 
       dbo.kayitlar.miktar, 
       dbo.kayitlar.fire 
FROM   dbo.isemri_data 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.kayitlar 
                    ON dbo.isemri_data.isemrino = dbo.kayitlar.isemrino 
       AND  dbo.kayitlar.tarih  >= '20150812'  -- use ANSI date YYYYMMDD
       AND  dbo.kayitlar.tarih <=  '20150819'  -- use ANSI date YYYYMMDD
       AND  CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), dbo.kayitlar.makina_id) = 'M1' 
       AND  dbo.kayitlar.isemrino LIKE '%'
```

Converting your datetime to a string means sql server treats them values as strings and not a date/datetime values hence you will get unexpected results Also sql server will not be able to make use of any indexes defined on that column if there are any.

Keep date/datetime values as it is and change the format of date in presentation layer for more easy to eyes date/datetime format.

Comment: But i cant change data type. because writing data this table from another program.

Comment: SELECT        ID, MAKINA_ID, PERSONEL, ISEMRINO, TARIH, GERCEK_HIZ, DURUS_KOD, MIKTAR, FIRE
FROM            dbo.KAYITLAR
WHERE        (CONVERT(varchar(3), MAKINA_ID) = 'M1') AND (ISEMRINO LIKE '%') AND (CONVERT(varchar(10), TARIH, 104) BETWEEN CONVERT(varchar(10), 
                         '18.08.2015 00:00:00', 104) AND CONVERT(varchar(10), '19.08.2015 00:00:00', 104))

Comment: this query is giving result? what do you thing for this?